# Lightshot on windows 11 is hard to install / troubleshoot

Tags: windows-11, snipping-tool

I got a new computer, Windows 11, and wants to replace snippet tool with Lightshot.

I uninstalled snippet tool, and installed Lightshot, but I don't think it installed 100% because there is no icon in the tools menu.

Also, if it did install then I am unsure if PrtSc on a Lenovo needs the Fn key, but it doesn't work with or without.

My hope was maybe something was written in the EventLog, but there isn't anything there.

Does anyone have good ideas for troubleshooting something like this.

**Added details to questions**
Lightshot does not start. There isn't even an icon near the clock. I have also tried to run the .exe (C:\Program Files (x86)\Skillbrains\lightshot\5.5.0.7), it just runs with no errors for half a sec and nothing happns.

I have tried to reinstall reboot etc.

(The OS is Windows 11 pro)

Comment: try using keyboard manager in powertoys to set the shortcut keys for lightshot

Comment: If a tool cannot change its hotkeys with Auto Hot Key or Power Toys, then consider not using it.

Comment: I suspect it isn't installed 100% and that is why it isn't available in powertoys.

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall? If so how was it? If not, why not? As always, [edit] to update the question with requested info.

Comment: Do the hotkeys work in Lightshot?

Comment: I'm having this same issue. Win11 22H2 here. I can see it on the process explorer but it isn't showing at the systray nor working when pressing the printscreen key

Comment: Same on a newly installed windows 11 22H2, process comes up, but does not bring up any windows

Comment: And I thought it was just me. Hope to get a workaround soon, Snipping Tools is not something I can live with. I think, I'll install Greenshot for the time being.

Comment: I removed lightshot. but the fact that the hotkeys no longer work I think is some bad change on win11 because some other software I'm using also no longer works like before.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking into it too, not sure if it would fix it, but in [this page](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-11-disable-snipping-tool-and-switch-to/8691ad8d-7c8f-481e-91a7-f80d492de19a) they mention that the PrtSc can't be used until it's freed from accessibility menu.

> Go to your settings menu, accessibility, keyboard. The second area is called on-screen keyboard, access keys, and print screen. Option 3 says "Use the print screen button to open screen snipping" . Turn that off and then you will be able to assign the printscrn button in Greenshot to the "select region" option and it will work properly. See images.